# A time series with 2 kinds of periods

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am attempting to analyze a time series which clearly presents two kinds of periods. The time series fluctuates periodically every week, and in addition it periodically rises at the end of every month.

I am trying to use ARIMA model to analyze it but how can I set two different kinds of periods in the function ARIMA? Or is there any other better model better explaining the series?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very handy package called `forecast` which has a function that accepts more than one frequencies,

```
install.packages('forecast')
library(forecast)

i1 <- msts(your_series, seasonal.periods = c(period_1, period_2))
forecast(i1, h = no. of points to forecast)
```

[This link](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/) gives some information about how to define seasonal periods

Otherwise, If you want to do it manually within `ARIMA` then you will have to add weekly and monthly dummy variables and pass them as an argument. 
[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205970/arima-model-with-weekday-dummy-variables-forecast) will clarify this methodology